# Using extended JSON with node.js mongodb native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I've been looking at extened json http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/ as I need my documents to survive a round trip from my web service to another service without loosing awareness of which data types were used on the original JavaScript object (object ids and dates).

Does the node is mongo native driver supports actually serializing a JavaScript object to extended JSON and also parsing extended JSON into a JavaScript object with the correct data types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this might do what you're looking for:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-extended-json